# php constant contact throwing error when creating campegin

Tags: php, sdk, constantcontact

hello every one need a help i am integrating the constant contact sdk in php
trying to deply [this](https://github.com/constantcontact/php-sdk) example from git.

when i am goin to create email campagin from example it throwing the below error

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [error_key] => http.status.bad_request
            [error_message] => Please enter an address
        )
)
```

> Note: I am trying to test it on my local environment any suggestion /help will be highly appreciated .

thanks .

Answer (score 0):

CAN-SPAM compliance requires every company to have a valid physical address.
In My Account > My Settings add an organization address; this should resolve your error.

Answer (score 0):

after a research on it i found the solution there is a section under my setting

My Settings -> Organization Address -> Edit Address

Organization Address. go there and fill the physical address of your organization which is mandatory to avoid the the email go in junk/spam..
after this the sdk works for me thanks for contribution...